# Cannot POST Form in Node

Tags: node.js

I am trying to post a simple form from a static page to a database and then re-render the page. Right now I am getting a "Cannot Post /Index" error.

Here is my the form code:

```
<div class="contact-form">
  <form action="/index" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="# of Trucks" name="truckNum">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" name="company">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" name="address">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="submit" class="form-control text-uppercase" value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the router code:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/../public/index.html"));
});

app.post("/", function(req,res){
    db.Contact.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            company:req.body.company,
            address:req.body.address,
            truckNumber:req.body.truckNum
        }).then(function(data) {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/../public/index.html"));
        });
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change '/index' to '/' in`<form action="/index" method="post">`.